# Using sibling child relationship in Email Template Merge field

Tags: email

I'm trying to create a standard HTML merge field to get additional information from a sibling child relationship, but whenever I enter it into the email template SF automatically gets rid of it.

Example merge field:

```
{!Account.Associate__r.Email_Header__c}
```

Account has a Related Lookup field called Associate_*c, the object Associate*_c has a field called Email_Header__c.

**Is this at all possible?** What is a work around that doesn't involve creating a formula on an Account (which would work, but is messy)

My main goal is to have a different email header/footer but based on the Associate__c in the account rather than letterheads which won't work for our business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this functionality doesn't currently work in Salesforce. While it is possible to save a email template with relationship fields - they simply don't work. See this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Brk7AAC) to have this fixed.